# Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I try to update one property in table from SelectedList

Here is my model

```
 public partial class Interwier
{
    [Key]
    public int Interwier_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ФИО")]
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Телефон")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "День рождения")]
    public System.DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Город")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Зарплата")]
    public string Salary { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Английский язык")]
    public string English { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> VacancyId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Vacancy Vacancy { get; set; }
}
```

I need to update `Status`  property.

Here is Edit action in controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Interwier interwierModel = db.InterwierModels.Find(id);
        if (interwierModel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(interwierModel);
    }

    // POST: Interwier/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,Telephone,Birthday,City,Salary,English,Status")] Interwier interwierModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(interwierModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Incoming");
        }
        return View(interwierModel);
    }
```

And here is how it looks on View

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 515px;">
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Подтвердить", Value = "Одобрено"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "Отправить в архив", Value = "Архив"},
                }, "Статус", new { @class = "form-control" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click submit button I have this error

[image]

How I can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `Interwier_id` property as hidden field. Use `HiddenFor` extension method. You don't post the ID to server that's why EF cannot find the entity in DB. Assuming the code below is within the `BeginForm` block.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Interwier_id)

<div class="form-group" style="padding-left: 515px;">
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Подтвердить", Value = "Одобрено"},
                new SelectListItem() {Text = "Отправить в архив", Value = "Архив"},
            }, "Статус", new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
</div>
```

And also update properties that you bind from Id to Interwier_id:

```
[Bind(Include = "Interwier_id,...")]
```

Comment: I need to write it like this or where?

`@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Interwier_id)
`

Comment: Yes, you need to do it inside form. I thought you already have it. You can place it next you `DropDownListFor` list.

Comment: Hm, I tried `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Interwier_id)` not works.

http://pastebin.com/jGenNqan

Maybe I do smth not right?

Comment: Like this?
`[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Email,Telephone,Birthday,City,Salary,English,Status")] Interwier interwierModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.InterwierModels.Attach(interwierModel);
                db.Entry(interwierModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Incoming");
            }
            return View(interwierModel);
        }`

Comment: No, sorry, Entry method does exactly that. I have updated the answer, looks like you didn't bind Id correctly.

Comment: Super, I'm glad it helped :)